# How to fill array with random numbers in Counting Sort Algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, counting, array-algorithms

```
#include iostream

using namespace std;

int k=0;    

void sort_func(int A[],int B[],int n)    
{
    int count[k+1],t;
    for(int i=0;i<=k;i++)
    {
        count[i] = 0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        t = A[i];
        count[t]++;         
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=k;i++)
    {
        count[i] = count[i]+count[i-1];            
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        t = A[i];
        B[count[t]] = t;          
        count[t]=count[t]-1;        
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter the size of the array :";
    cin>>n;
    int A[n],B[n]; 
    cout<<"Enter the array elements: ";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)        
    {
        cin>>A[i];
        if(A[i]>k)
        {
            k = A[i];              
        }
    }
    sort_func(A,B,n);        
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)       
    {
        cout<<B[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This is the C++ code for Counting Sort Algorithm and i can not change the code to create random array without entering values one by one
edit:Yes i meant to create random values in array A by using rand() function.

Comment: What is your question?   How to create random values in A?

Comment: std::generate(A, A + SIZE, std::rand);

Comment: `int A[n],B[n];` Be careful with this line. Arrays of variable size are not part of the standard and may not work in other compilers.

Answer (score 1):

You have different options for filling an array with random elements. Just to name a few:

- `rand()` without a seed: pseudo-random number generator; and you get the same sequence of numbers every time you run the program. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rK1M9sr4a)

```cpp
std::generate(A, A + n, []() { return std::rand() % 101; });
```

- `rand()` with a seed: pseudo-random number generator; depending on the seed you use, you can get a new sequence of numbers every time you run the program; for example, if you use `time(NULL)` as seed, which returns the current time in seconds since a given date, you would get a new sequence of numbers whenever you get a new output from `time`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Yjad37Efh)

```cpp
std::srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(NULL)));
std::generate(A, A + n, []() { return std::rand() % 101; });
```

- `default_random_engine` with a seed from `random_device`, for generating random numbers, and `uniform_int_distribution`, for distributing those random numbers uniformly in a given range: non-deterministic number generator or, in case a non-deterministic source is not available to the implementation, a pseudo-random number generator. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/K55K3Yhvq)

As @NO_NAME pointed out in one of their comments, `random_device()` can throw. If you use this option, you can fall back to a `rand()` solution if you catch an exception. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/r3ef95cnM)

```cpp
using random_generator = std::function<int()>;
random_generator rg{};
try
{
    std::default_random_engine random_engine{ std::random_device{}() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist{0, 100};
    rg = [&uniform_dist, &random_engine]() { return uniform_dist(random_engine); };
}
catch (const std::exception& ex)
{
    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(NULL)));
    rg = []() { return std::rand() % 101; };
}
std::generate(A, A + n, rg);
```

As an aside note, you could use `max_element` to calculate `k` in your code:

```cpp
k = *std::max_element(A, A + n);
```

Comment: Note that `random_device` is an advanced random engine that may not be available in some systems.

Comment: More precisely: "[std::random_device](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) is a non-deterministic uniform random bit generator, although implementations are allowed to implement std::random_device using a pseudo-random number engine if there is no support for non-deterministic random number generation." What, if I understand correctly, means that, in the worst case, it behaves as the `srand` with a given seed plus `rand` combo.

Comment: From https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/random_device/ : "Notice that random devices may not always be available to produce random numbers (and in some systems, they may even never be available). This is signaled by throwing an exception derived from the standard exception on construction or when a number is requested with operator()."

Comment: @NO_NAME Many thanks for the comment. I didn't know that. I'll update the answer considering that info.